# Extracting variables from set of strings in python

Tags: python, string

I have a set of strings that I extracted and stored into an array. Some of these contain variables that I want to extract, the problem is these are strings at the moment. So for example, one string would look like

```
s1 = 'DataFile=scan1.dat'
```

Others would look like

```
s2 = 'NumberOfChannels=32'
```

What I want to do is take s1 and s2 and extract from them info and store them as such:

```
DataFile='scan1.dat'
NumberOfChannels=32
```

The strings all look similar to the ones above. It's either a variable that contains a string itself, or a variable containing an integer. Here's my (failed) attempt at the integer case:

```
            # ll is a string element of the big array

            if ll.startswith('NumberOfChannels'): 
                print "found nChans"
                idx = ll.index('=')
                vars()[ll[:idx-1]] = int(ll[idx+1:])
```

Any suggestions/external modules that could help me out would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is a common question, but this practice is frowned upon in Python because it is not only dangerous (you can easily shadow a builtin) but also an horrid namespace pollution. Store key/values in a dict, a separate namespace (or use a dummy object as a namespace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def convert(val):
    """
    Attempt to coerce type of val in following order: int, float, str
    """
    for type in (int, float, str):
        try:
            return type(val)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return val

def make_config(*args, **kwargs):
    for arg in args:
        try:
            key,val = arg.split('=')
            kwargs[key.strip()] = convert(val.strip())
        except ValueError:   # .split() didn't return two items
            pass
    return kwargs

s1 = 'DataFile=scan1.dat'
s2 = 'NumberOfChannels=32'
config = make_config(s1, s2)
```

which gives you

```
{'DataFile': 'scan1.dat', 'NumberOfChannels': 32}
```

Comment: +1 for this for being so easy to use, but why do you attempt to convert to `str` in the `convert()` function? The value is always `str` by default

Answer (score 1):

While this is might not be the best way of achieving whatever you are trying, here is a way of doing it:

```
string_of_interest = 'NumberOfChannels=32'
string_split = string_of_interest.split('=')
globals() [ string_split[0] ] = string_split[1]
```

---

EDIT: (From comments), you can try

```
globals() [ string_split[0] ] = eval(string_split[1])
```

if you trust the type conversion.

Comment: alternatively, `eval(ll,globals())` if you trust the input.

Comment: @isedev Have you tried using `eval()` in this case? It produces a SyntaxError exception.

Comment: yeah, it would for the string, not the integer. Good point :)

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification, you can use `exec` for this;

```
In [1]: exec('NumberOfChannels = 32')

In [2]: NumberOfChannels
Out[2]: 32

In [3]: exec('DataFile="scan1.dat"')

In [4]: DataFile
Out[4]: 'scan1.dat'
```

Note that you should *never* feed untrusted code to `exec`!

And loading random variables into your program is generally a bad idea. What if the variable names are the same as some used in your program?

If you want to store configuration data, have a look at [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead.

```
In [6]: import json

In [7]: json.dumps({'NumberOfChannels': 32, 'DataFile': 'scan1.dat'})
Out[7]: '{"DataFile": "scan1.dat", "NumberOfChannels": 32}'

In [8]: json.loads('{"DataFile": "scan1.dat", "NumberOfChannels": 32}')
Out[8]: {u'DataFile': u'scan1.dat', u'NumberOfChannels': 32}

In [9]: config = json.loads('{"DataFile": "scan1.dat", "NumberOfChannels": 32}')

In [10]: config['DataFile']
Out[10]: u'scan1.dat'
```